# Chrome Javascript Console: Get table data across mult. pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am trying to collect data from a html `<table>` that extends across multiple pages using javscript in the chrome 'inspect element'>>'console'. So far I can successfully:

1. Get data from page 1 into the array
2. Open each page using window.open(...)

However, after opening the any of the other pages the appended data always corresponds to the 1st page. So instead of data from 13 pages I get data from page 1 repeated 13 times. Here is the code:

```
// 'mypage' contains 13 pages of tabular data. Each page is accessed with '&page='
var page = "mypage/?q=&page=";
var pages = 13;
var arr = [];

// loop through all pages
for( var i=1; i<=pages; i++){
    // this opens the next page on browser but the data corresponds to page 1
    var doc = window.open(page + i,"_top").document;
    var table = $(doc).find("table tbody")[0];

    // loops through each row of the table and takes only column 6
    $(table).find('tr').each( function() {
        var row = $(this).find('td');
        arr.push($(row[6]).text());
    });
}

// do something with arr, but it only contains page=1 data repeated 13 times.
```

Comment: is window.open synchronous, does halt the execution of the function, or does the whole thing just finish before the next page is loaded?

Comment: the whole script runs right through, and doesn't seem like it waits for each page to load. I've tried using $(doc).ready(function(){...}); to delay searching the table until after the page loads, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: doc was ready as soon as it loaded the page your script is on. maybe you can try building in a delay... i've never tried any of this. you can try finding a way to detect the NEW page's onload function like `var win = window.open("...");
win.onload = function(){
    // Do something
}`

Comment: Thanks, it does seem to be because it's not waiting for the page to load, but using onload does not work either.